# getting error when try to run "rasa x" in terminal using anaconda3 with python 3.7.0

Tags: python, django, chatbot, rasa, rasa-x

(rasa_conda_env) C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\rasa_conda>rasa x
Starting Rasa X in local mode... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\x.py", line 502, in run_locally
domain_path=domain_path,
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\local.py", line 226, in main
rasax.community.jwt.initialise_jwt_keys()
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\jwt.py", line 68, in initialise_jwt_keys
private_key, public_key = cryptography.generate_rsa_key_pair()
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\rasax\community\cryptography.py", line 28, in generate_rsa_key_pair
backend=default_backend(),
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends_*init*_.py", line 14, in default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl_*init*_.py", line 6, in 
from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py", line 113, in 
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\rasa_conda_env\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 14, in 
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Sorry, something went wrong (see error above). Make sure to start Rasa X with valid data and valid domain and config files. Please, also check any warnings that popped up.
If you need help fixing the issue visit our forum: https://forum.rasa.com/.

Comment: This message: `DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found` generally indicates a version mismatch. The loading process is expecting to find a specific named entry point in the DLL and not finding it. So the DLL is a different version from what the calling code is expecting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run rasa x locally on a windows machine, then I would recommend using docker and wsl2.

From your Rasa assistant's project directory, start Rasa X with:

```sh
docker run --rm \
 -v $(pwd):/app \
 -p 5002:5002 \
 --entrypoint rasa rasa/rasa-x:latest x
```

Comment: thanks...but what if without docker i want to use rasa x as my laptop configrations not good

Comment: Docker's system requirements aren't that high-end: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/

Does your laptop not meet the requirements above?